# Determine whether or not the following series is convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Determine whether or not the following series is convergent $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$$

What test should I use to approach this question?

Comment: $\;n-$th root test gives immediate answer.

Comment: $1/n^n < 1/n^2$

Answer (score 1):

When the ratio test works, it is normally the easiest to apply. Here
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\frac1{n+1}$$
Since $$0\le\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\le1$$ and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1{n+1}=0$$
We can conclude that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=0$$
So

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^n}$$
Converges by the ratio test.

Comment: Your 2nd display line needs fixing. I suggest  replacing it with $0<(n/(n+1))^n<1$.

Comment: @user254665: you're right, I copied the wrong chunk of MathJax in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*
Compare this sum with $\sum{\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}}$

Comment: This requires knowing and proving $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} $, thus I don't think it helps the questioner much.

Comment: @Imago hm.. Maybe , I just present him a one hint, maybe he know Weierstrass test